# Tumblr glitch with ask page CAPTCHA

Tags: tumblr, captcha

I've been trying to find out details on how to fix this with Tumblr:

[image: Glitch]

I'm trying to allow anonymous people to send me messages. However, when people try to send me something they need to fill a CAPTCHA, which messes up the ask box layout and renders them unable to post. I haven't found any details by googling, and when I try to edit the theme’s source code I can't get to the ask page HTML.

Any details on how to get this done or maybe disable the CAPTCHA?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off SSL.
I had the same issue after setting the SSL toggle on (it's in "edit appearance"). Turning off SSL fixed the issue and the captcha works now. I emailed Tumblr to let them know, hopefully it's a quick fix.

Comment: Not ideal, and as of 2020 not even possible anymore. I actually had to throw around some custom HTML to fix this. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

See the custom page I had to add to tumblr to fix this:

https://the-null-log.org/askme